# How do I track clicks on <a> tag with span class inside using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: html, css, google-tag-manager

I've been trying to get GTM to fire a tag every time a user clicks on the link text below ("Click here to donate").

```
  <a href="https://www.testurl.com/donate" target="_blank" >
  <span class="donate"><img src="donate-icon.png"></span>
  Click here to donate!    </a>
```

I'm able to get the tag to fire when users click on the image by using trigger with the following settings below. But I can't get the tag to fire when users click on the link text.

Trigger type: Click - All Elements

Trigger fires on: Some Clicks

Click Element --> matches CSS selector --> .donate

*Note: I'm unable to insert any CSS into the A tag directly due to the site template not being directly controlled by me. I could make a request but it would take weeks if not longer to get the necessary approvals and work done.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following setup using `Click URL` instead of `Click Element`:

- *Trigger type:* Click - All Elements
- *Trigger fires on:* Some Clicks
- *Click URL:* `https://www.testurl.com/donate`

or another solution could be:

- *Trigger type:* Click - All Elements
- *Trigger fires on:* Some Clicks
- *Click Text:* `Click here to donate!`

> **solutions based on:** https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en#Click

Another possiblity would be to use the trigger type `Click - Just Links`:

- *Trigger type:* Click - Just Links
- *Trigger fires on:* Some Link Clicks
- *Click URL:* `https://www.testurl.com/donate`

---

**What if you have no text or URL?**
In this case you can track an element with a specific `class` attribute:

- *Trigger type:* Click - All Elements
- *Trigger fires on:* Some Clicks
- *Click Classes:* `toggle-sidebar` (or a more specific class)

Comment: I added one more possibility using the trigger type `Click - Just Links`

Comment: Having "just links" was the solution for me.

Comment: What if you have no text or URL?  I have a toggle show hide I am looking to track the icon has an animation so it cannot be moved to the style sheet <a href="#" id="toggle-sidebar" class="toggle-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-plus rotate"></i></a>

Comment: @esoteric - added a possibility.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBrosch, I tied that with the same result, it works when you click on the link but if you click on the icon it does not register in Google Analytics.

Comment: @esoteric - You tried `<a href="#" id="toggle-sidebar" class="toggle-sidebar my-trigger-class"><i class="fa fa-plus rotate my-trigger-class"></i></a>` (my-trigger-class is the the click class on the tag manager)?

Answer (score 0):

"Just Links" didn't seem to work for me in one particularly confusing case. It wasn't clear why, but clicks on a certain  tag weren't registering as link clicks, and the "All Elements" click was registering on the inner element, so I had to improvise.

The solution that is working best for me is to render the inner elements invisible with regard to clicks using pointer-events: none. This will make the click pass through the inner elements and hit the anchor tag so that the  tag can be recognized by HREF parameters.

I use this in the context of mailto and tel links.

My trigger looks like this:

```
Click - All Elements
Some Clicks
Click URL Contains tel:
```

And then I add a tag called "Click Event Helper" with this custom HTML:

```
<style>
  a[href*="tel"] *, a[href*="mailto"] * {
     pointer-events: none !important; 
  }
</style>
```

This CSS tells every element inside an  tag that contains tel or mailto to let clicks pass through it up to the a tag, which is then successfully read by the GTM Trigger.

In the OP's case, here's what I would do:

Trigger:

```
Click - All Elements 
Some Clicks 
Click URL Contains /donate
```

Helper Tag:

```
<style>
  a[href*="donate"] * {
     pointer-events: none !important; 
  }
</style>
```

This will catch all clicks on your donate link, even when you have inner HTML styling and when you have different text on buttons, etc...

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can add css class with jquery 
    .addClass('donate')

and that should works for you if you can add JS to your page